# Rollapply in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, posixct, rollapply

So, what I am doing is creating a heatmap for `x` and `y` coordinates. But I would like to do this for every 30 minute interval. For example the first heatmap will be created using the data from `"00:00:00"` to `"00:30:00"`, then the next from `"00:01:00"` to `"00:31:00"`.

What I need help with is writing a for loop that can extract these rows from a larger database and then spit out the heatmap for each bracket of data. I have been told that `zoo::rollapply` could be useful in the process but am not sure how it works.

The database has three columns `x`, `y`, and `indiv.times`. `x` and `y` are the coordinate systems and `indiv.times` is a character variable which contains the times in the format `"13:04:46"` for example.

```
for (i in ???) {
  kde <- kde2d(x, y)
  plot_ly(z = kde$z, type = "heatmap")
}
```

This is the code to create the heatmap so I really just need a way to extract the 30 minute intervals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample of the database:

```
structure(list(x = c(224.7666, 223.3886, 131.7025, 345.333), 
    y = c(60.7657, 85.73872, 77.35342, 26.24607), indiv.times = Sys.time() +
    cumsum(60*sample(20, size = 10, replace = TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone else is interested, I created an index `i` that has all the times from `"00:00:00"` all the way to `"24:00:00"`. Than inside the `for` loop you just need to extract the rows from the data frame where `df[time < i + 1800 & time > i,]`. Make sure your times are in the time format and not just strings. Then you can perform any adjustments in the for loop using the new extracted data frame.